# How to customize pub global executables

Tags: dart

When I see my *$HOME/.pub-cache/bin* executables the normal template is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# This file was created by pub v1.24.2.
# Package: <package>
# Version: <package_version>
# Executable: <package>
# Script: <package>
pub global run <package>:<package> "$@"
```

However things go different with [stagehand](https://github.com/dart-lang/stagehand)

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# This file was created by pub v1.24.2.
# Package: stagehand
# Version: 1.1.6
# Executable: stagehand
# Script: stagehand
dart "$HOME/.pub-cache/global_packages/stagehand/bin/stagehand.dart.snapshot" "$@"

# The VM exits with code 253 if the snapshot version is out-of-date.
# If it is, we need to delete it and run "pub global" manually.
exit_code=$?
if [ $exit_code != 253 ]; then
  exit $exit_code
fi

pub global run stagehand:stagehand "$@"
```

I would like to know how to achieve this customization without post-install hacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that stagehand registers an executable.

See https://github.com/dart-lang/stagehand/blob/be67e5a6647f1bdf4aa773e7a40ed75a534b92c4/pubspec.yaml#L22

This means you can just run `stagehand` and it works.

It also means that a snapshot is created for that executable (as you noticed).

See also https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec#executables

Add an executables section to your pubspec and you should be golden!

Edit: also, you won't get this with path-activated packages. The idea: ensure you keep running from your local source.

Comment: I see... But doing that with my packages doesn't build a snapshot, I neither found documentation about that nor I found any of those words in the stagehand github repo that gives me the clue that the customization is a post-install hack.

Comment: @NicoRodsevich – so doing 'pub global activate' with your package hosted on the pub site (or git) doesn't create a snapshot?

Comment: It works!
The problem apparently was in a typo in an old package, and in the other package test, I was intalling from --source path my own package. When trying, as you said, with git it worked well. Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear, @NicoRodsevich!